# rosparam load key is giving errors when i try to list the parameters available to the node

Tags: ros-melodic, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a package called pkg_ros_basics. Then inside that, I created a folder called scripts and inside which i made a folder called config inside which I created a file using touch config_my.yaml and gedit config_my.yaml

then inside this i wrote
#inside config_my.yaml

```
details:
          name:
                  first: "Hisenberg"
                  last: "White"
          contact:
                  address: "Random Street"
                  phone: 77777
```

Then when i do rosparam load config_my.yaml, It is expected that these 4 paramters from config_my.yaml is also visible but instead i get a huge error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosparam", line 35, in 
rosparam.yamlmain()
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 622, in yamlmain
_rosparam_cmd_set_load(command, argv)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 541, in _rosparam_cmd_set_load
paramlist = load_file(arg, default_namespace=script_resolve_name(NAME, arg2), verbose=options.verbose)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 175, in load_file
return load_str(f.read(), filename, default_namespace=default_namespace, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 189, in load_str
for doc in yaml.safe_load_all(str):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/init.py", line 83, in load_all
yield loader.get_data()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 33, in get_data
return self.construct_document(self.get_node())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 27, in get_node
return self.compose_document()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
node = self.compose_node(None, None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
self.current_event = self.state()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 449, in parse_block_mapping_value
if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
self.fetch_more_tokens()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
% ch.encode('utf-8'), self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
in "", line 4, column 1:
name:
^

#I request you all to help me solve this problem as i am a beginner in ROS. ThankYou!

I have created a package called pkg_ros_basics. Inside the package, I have a folder called scripts where I made another folder called config where I typed in some name-value pairs as the following

#inside config_my.yaml

```
   details:
   
              name:
                      first: "hisenberg"
                      last: "white"
   

               contact:
                          address: "Random street"
                          phone: 77777
```

Then I closed this and put rosparam load config_my.yaml and got this huge error, I would like you to guide me to solve this and  help me as i am a beginner in ROS :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rosparam", line 35, in 
rosparam.yamlmain()
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 622, in yamlmain
_rosparam_cmd_set_load(command, argv)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 541, in _rosparam_cmd_set_load
paramlist = load_file(arg, default_namespace=script_resolve_name(NAME, arg2), verbose=options.verbose)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 175, in load_file
return load_str(f.read(), filename, default_namespace=default_namespace, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/init.py", line 189, in load_str
for doc in yaml.safe_load_all(str):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/init.py", line 83, in load_all
yield loader.get_data()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 33, in get_data
return self.construct_document(self.get_node())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 27, in get_node
return self.compose_document()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
node = self.compose_node(None, None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
self.current_event = self.state()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 449, in parse_block_mapping_value
if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
self.fetch_more_tokens()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 257, in fetch_more_tokens
% ch.encode('utf-8'), self.get_mark())
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
in "", line 4, column 1:
name:
^

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381748/rosparam-load-key-is-giving-errors-when-i-try-to-list-the-parameters-available-to-the-node/) by [Naufal_Abubacker](https://answers.ros.org/users/77142/naufal_abubacker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2021-07-05**:
PLEASE modify your question into a precise format, it's difficult to read everything.
Also please format your error into inline code format by adding ``` before and after the error

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
Are you using tabs? The tab character is not valid in the yaml syntax.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
P.S. Storing a phone number as an integer is going to cause you huge problems in the future.

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2021-07-08**:
@Mike Scheutzow What's the right way? Storing it as a string?
Yeah I guess String makes more sense

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-08**:
@electrophod Yes, a string is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tab character is not valid in the yaml syntax.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naufal_Abubacker](https://answers.ros.org/users/77142/naufal_abubacker/) on 2021-07-08**:
Yes sir, thank You so much for this, when i tried with space keys it worked Perfectly!!!